# Hook for running image editing algorithms when a new image is uploaded to WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress, hook

I'm trying to implement a functionality in WordPress where image editing algorithms are executed automatically every time a new image is uploaded. I want to call another server to process the editing, but I'm unsure about which hook to use for triggering this action.

I attempted to use the following code:

```
add_action('add_attachment', 'send_image_to_remote_server');
```

However, it doesn't appear to be working as expected.

Could someone please suggest the correct hook to use in order to call my server and send the API address of the newly uploaded image for editing?

Thank you in advance for any assistance provided.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to trigger an action and send the API address of a newly uploaded image to a remote server for editing, you can use the add_attachment hook in WordPress. However, the add_attachment hook is fired before the attachment metadata is saved to the database, so the API address might not be available at that point.

To ensure that the API address is available when the hook is triggered, you can use the wp_insert_attachment hook instead. This hook is fired after the attachment metadata is saved to the database. Here's an example of how you can modify your code:

```
add_action('wp_insert_attachment', 'send_image_to_remote_server', 10, 3);

function send_image_to_remote_server($attachment_id, $post_data, $update) {
    // Get the API address of the uploaded image
    $api_address = ''; // Replace with your logic to retrieve the API address

    // Make sure the API address is available
    if (!empty($api_address)) {
        // Call your remote server and send the API address
        // Replace this with your code to send the API address to the remote server
    }
}
```

In the `send_image_to_remote_server` function, you can retrieve the API address of the uploaded image using your own logic. Once you have the API address, you can proceed to send it to the remote server for editing.

Make sure to replace the placeholder '' with your logic to retrieve the actual API address of the image. Additionally, replace the comment with your own code to send the API address to the remote server for editing.

By using the `wp_insert_attachment` hook, you can ensure that the API address is available and ready to be sent to the remote server after the attachment metadata is saved to the database.

Comment: I have included the code snippet, but I'm not receiving any requests on my server for some reason.

add_action('wp_insert_attachment', 'send_image_to_remote_server', 10, 3);
function send_image_to_remote_server($attachment_id, $post_data, $update) {
  $image_path = get_attached_file( $attachment_id );
  $ch = curl_init("http://localhost:8082/upload-image?path=" . $image_path);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
  $data = curl_exec($ch);
  curl_close($ch);
}

I would highly appreciate any insights or suggestions you may have.